# Qt - Overriding ResizeEvent give multiple calls when showed

Tags: qt, events, resize

I get this strange behavior with a simple reimplementation of ResizeEvent from a standard Widget. After calling show, the resize event is called 2 times. I trace the behavior with breakpoint (see where below "<- - - -") and I got this :

- first call :

  - event->oldSize = (-1, -1)
  - event->size = (5, 13)
- second call :

  - event->oldSize = (640, 480)
  - event->size = (640, 480)

The first call seem coherent. But, is anyone can explain to me why I got a second call with inconsistant values and how to get rid of this second resize event?

```
class MyClass : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0);
   ~MyClass();

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
};

MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f)
: QLabel(parent, f)
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

void MyClass::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    int a = 0;  //   <- - - - use break point here
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyClass w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Are you using a tiling window manager or something?

Comment: Absolutely not. All the code is above. Only creating the new widget and showing it.

Comment: Does the label geometry really change to 640x480?

Comment: Another strange behavior I cannot explained is this sequence :
 1. first call to resizeEvent    (ok it's obvious)
 2. call to showEvent    (ok again)
 3. second call to resizeEvent   (???)

Comment: Which OS/Desktop Environment/Window Manager?

Comment: Using Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Could be related to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36459

Comment: I think the sequence you see is pretty common. Is it a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your last question make me do some tests and I found a solution.

I just add in the constructor :

```
this->setGeometry(...)
```

With that, I got only one resizeEvent call (the first one).

I do not know why Qt make this second call but I can guess is to set an initial geometry.

However, thank you for your time. It help me a lot!  :-)